# what is machine in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I was reading "professional asp.net 4.0 in C# and vb.net" and I saw this satement:

> The `Application` object is not global to the machine; it is global to the `HttpApplication`.

I don't know, what is machine in this statement?! What does machine mean?!

Comment: It just refers to the Computer your code runs on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Machine is the server, that the process hosting the ASP.NET process, is running on.

Usually, but not always this is IIS. But it could be any code that hosts the ASP.NET runtime - like [cassini](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188791.aspx) (an open source webserver provided in VS2008+ and now an [open source project in it's own right](http://weblogs.asp.net/tanzimsaqib/archive/2010/05/10/announcing-cassini-4-0.aspx)).

Anyway this means that if you have two hosting processes (using the above critera) then the Application object is not shared by both these processes. There will be a single Application object in each of those processes.

This is one of [my favourite articles about the ASP.NET and the HTTP pipeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188942.aspx). It presents lots of background information to how ASP.net hangs togeher, I think you might find useful.

Comment: @MesutDarvishian: Cassini is the built-in web server provided by Visual Studio 2008(?) and above

Comment: thanks that was very useful but i don't understand very well a section of your answer: "Anyway this means that if you two hosting processes (using the above critera) then the Application object is not shared by both these processes. There will be a single Application object in both of thse processes." please tell me more.

Comment: What about a process is totally independent from it's memory layout, so it is NOT a single application object in both processes as both processes are independent copies of the application. This is the WHOLE sense of having a web garden style setup with multiple processes.